# Can't get item back from local storage in react

Tags: reactjs

what is wrong here ?
i can set the item on localstorage but can't retrieve them back...

```
 <code>  
// getItem
 useEffect(function() {
 // var oldTodos = JSON.parse(locatStorage.getItem(l_key));
 // console.log(JSON.parse(locatStorage.getItem(l_key))
 console.log(locatStorage.getItem(l_key))
},[])

useEffect(function(){

localStorage.setItem(l_key, JSON.stringify(todos));

},[todos])

<code>
```

i am getting this error
'locatStorage' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: typos `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

loca**L** maybe instead of loca**T**